# Duplicate UI - in what conditions do they appear?

Tags: support, duplicates, exact-duplicates

I recently saw four different duplicate UIs in questions that are closed as a duplicate:

(1.)

> **This question already has an answer here:**
>
> [Minor key and its chords](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/50040/minor-key-and-its-chords/)

(2.)

> **This question is an exact duplicate of:**
>
> [Inaccurate reputation graphs - bug or as designed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271668/inaccurate-reputation-graphs-bug-or-as-designed)

(3.)

> **This question may already have an answer here:**
>
> [Is the message "This question may already have an answer here" shown after flags or only after close votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280051/is-the-message-this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-shown-after-flags)

(4.)

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>
> [Are modes and scales the same?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/are-modes-and-scales-the-same)

---

It seems like each of them appear in different conditions.  In what cases do they appear?

Comment: Can you give a real example of this instead of just linking to your post? I think you are get a lot of different contexts mixed up. I know 4 is only displayed in comments when someone first proposes a duplicate close.

Comment: @Dom - OK!  Fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

> This question already has an answer here:
>
> Minor key and its chords

My guess is that message appears when a question is closed as a duplicate. I'm pretty sure that's where I've seen it.

> This question is an exact duplicate of:
>
> Inaccurate reputation graphs - bug or as designed?

I'm not sure about this one, sorry. I'm not sure I've even seen it...

> This question may already have an answer here:
>
> Is the message "This question may already have an answer here" shown after flags or only after close votes?

I think that's the message shown when OP views their own question, probably as motivation to check out that question and make sure it's not a duplication. I think that  message appears when a duplicate is suggested by another user (but not yet closed or marked as a duplicate).

> Possible Duplicate:
>
> Are modes and scales the same?

I remember seeing those exact words as comments under the post when a duplicate is suggested, but I can't recall ever seeing a UI for it.

Pretty sure 1) is correct, but the others slipped my mind.